# Error configuring Remote Desktop for an Azure Web Role

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, azure-web-roles

We have and old Windows Azure Web Role solution that was using SDK 1.4. Since this SDK is now deprecated, we needed to upgrade it and used Visual Studio 2012 to open and upgrade the old VS2010 solution. It upgraded fine (to SDK 1.8).

When trying to configure Remote Desktop, however, Visual Studio 2012 threw the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Security.Cryptography, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Is this a known issue and is there a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about that specific error, but I would recommend not enabling RDP via Visual Studio.  Instead deploy without RDP and then use the Azure Management portal (or Powershell) to enable RDP post-deployment.  This uses the cloud service extension model instead of the plugin model and is generally a better option.

See http://gauravmantri.com/2013/05/06/windows-azure-cloud-services-extensions-and-service-management-api-fun-with-remote-desktop/ for more info.

Comment: Perfect, that's a great alternative to using VS for configuring Remote Desktop.